# How to extend a javascript object to include a method using _.extend or $.extend?

Tags: javascript

For example using *Underscore* library, the following code works:

```
var myobject = {};
_.extend(myobject, { 
  method: 'demo'
});
```

Here, `myobject.method` prints demo. But the following example does not work, *myboject.method is undefined*, when I set the value of `method` to be a function instead of a string:

```
var myobject = {};
_.extend(myobject, { 
  method: function() {
    return 'demo'
  });
});
```

Comment: Syntax is not right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `);`

```
var myobject = {};
_.extend(myobject, { 
  method: function() {
    return 'demo'
  } // ); <-- remove this
});
```